# iOS secondary language localization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I properly set localization for es (Spanish), en (English) and ca (Catalan). Spanish and English are primary while the secondaries are like es-xx and en-xx. Catalan is a secondary that has es-ca code. 
Problem is that if I launch the app for example with en-us, en.lproj resources are called because en-us does not exist. Good until this point but, if I remove catalan localization, should do the same and load primary one, es. However, does not load it and loads default one instead (en). I am missing anything? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're modeling the problem the right way.

The problem with removing Catalan (not sure why you'd remove a localization) is it will fall back to Spanish correct?  I assume people in Barcelona and who speak Catalan also speak Spanish but it doesn't feel right to change the language on those users.

In my app I offer English (both UK, US), French, Japanese and Spanish.  At startup I get the user's preferred locale and use an NSDictionary to map them to the most appropriate match and if no match is found I fallback to US English.  For instance if you live in South Africa the closest English is UK English but if you live in the Philippines US English is more appropriate.

Catalan users will fallback to English unfortunately but in the next version I'll be letting users specify their preferred language from the supported language list as well so they can fallback to Spanish in the future.

Try using NSDictionary to map the user's locale to your app's available languages and see if it solves your issue.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your reply. This could be a solution. Could you please provide an example about how to map user's locale to available languages? Thanks

Comment: Hi, it's super simple really...  You just populate a dictionary with the locales the user might use as the dictionary keys and make the dictionary values be the locale your app supports.  So if you wanted to map Mexican Spanish to Spain's Spanish you might have [mutableDictionary setObject: @"es_ES" forKey: @"es_MX"];

Comment: Not mentioned here, but in case it's not obvious, you would then override the default system locale with the selected locale for your application.